# Windows forms application calendar

Tags: .net, winforms, calendar

How to add a holiday list in a month calendar control in windows forms application?

Answer (score 3):

You could make the holiday days bold, for example in c#:

```
DateTime myVacation1 = new DateTime(2001, 6, 10);
DateTime myVacation2 = new DateTime(2001, 6, 17);

monthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(myVacation1);
monthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(myVacation2);

// or if it is every year:
monthCalendar1.AddAnnuallyBoldedDate(myVacation2);
```

For more info check this link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983564%28v=vs.71%29.aspx